# Toggle Class of <i> inside a <a> on click of <a>

Tags: jquery, toggleclass

I am looking to toggle the class of an icon which is inside of a link once the link is clicked. I have it working at the moment but when clicked all my icons change - I have more than one accordion on the page. I only want to change the icon of the link that is clicked. Can anyone help? I know it must be to do with 'this' but I can't figure it out.

**jQuery code**

```
$( ".accordion a" ).click(function() {
    $( ".accordion a i" ).toggleClass('fa-caret-up ','fa-caret-down');
});
```

**HTML code**

```
<a href="#panel{accordion_number}">{accordion_heading} <i class="fa fa-caret-down linkIcon"></i></a>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are not using the `.toggleClass()` signature properly. The signature that you are trying to use on it is `.toggleClass('class1 class2')`

Try,

```
$( ".accordion a" ).click(function() {
  $(this).find("i").toggleClass('fa-caret-up fa-caret-down');
});
```

And I missed to explain it, you need to use `$(this)` inside the click event to target the currently clicked element. Otherwise it would affect all the elements matching the selector.

Comment: No it affect all accordion

Comment: @Jai haha.. great.. :)

Answer (score 1):

Use `.find` like below :

```
$( ".accordion a" ).click(function() {
    $(this).find("i").toggleClass('fa-caret-up fa-caret-down');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

1) ToggleClass is wrong syntax

2) Use current element $(this)

```
$( ".accordion a" ).click(function() {

    $(this).find("i").toggleClass('fa-caret-up fa-caret-down');

});
```

Comment: Thanks for downvoting :-)

Comment: Please see the Jquery top users page..! :) :) :D

Comment: Wow, Congrats keep it up

Answer (score 0):

Using `this` reference to get current element and find to get `i`, and change

Try this

```
$( ".accordion a" ).click(function() {
    $( this ).find('i').toggleClass('fa-caret-up fa-caret-down');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

As already posted you need to find the specific "i" in the link you click. 
HOWEVER you likely also need to stop the link from going anywhere

```
$( ".accordion a" ).click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault(); // needed if you want to stay on the page
  $(this).find("i").toggleClass('fa-caret-up fa-caret-down');
});
```